# Is it possible to manage local state within Vue component by Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Currently, I'm using Vuex for managing application-level state.

I need to store data only within the Vue component lifecycle. Is it possible to use Vuex for storing local component states without involving the global store?

For example, I have a component like that:

```js
class SomeComponent extends Vue {
  id = this.$props.componentId;
  localData = {};

  async created() {
    this.localData = await apiClient.getDataById(this.id);
  }
}
```

Then I can use components with different prop `componentId`, and every component should manage its own state.

```html
<SomeComponent componentId="1" />
<SomeComponent componentId="2" />
<SomeComponent componentId="3" />
```

So ideal variant I'd like to see:

```js
import LocalStore from './local-store';

class SomeComponent extends Vue {
  id = this.$props.componentId;
  localStore = new LocalStore(); // <- this is the Vuex store

  created() {
    localStore.getDataById(this.id);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is most definitely possible. i've never used the class-based syntax, but in object based syntax, it would look something like this

```html
<div>
  <p>{{ state1 }}<p>
  <p>{{ state2 }}</p>
  <p>{{ localState }}</p>
</div>
```

```js
export default {
  computed: {
    state1() {
      return this.$store.state.state1;
    }
    state2() {
      return this.$store.state.state2;
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
       localState: 3
    }
  },
  props: {
    componentId: {
      type: Number
  },
}
```

again, ive never used the class base syntax, but it might look like this pseudocode

```js
import { Prop } from 'vue-class-component'

export default class App extends Vue {
  get state1() {
    return this.$store.state.state1;
  }
  get state2() {
    return this.$store.state.state2;
  }

  localState = 3

  @Prop()
  componentId: Number
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I wrongly describe the problem. I'd like to use Vuex as the local state instead of built-in Vue data states.

Comment: @Ky6uk oh, i get ya. uh, i dont think thats possible (i wish i could give a definitive answer, as i haven't tried to build in app in that way before). you can probably access the state via `this.$store.state.variable` or something, but it will not be reactive. vuex is pretty tightly coupled with vue, so maybe you want to shop for another state management solution or change your approach